# Laravel 5.5 How to read flash data in a view page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-views

[image: How can I print a]
[image]

My Controller is redirecting to this View with flash data(data from a table row). How do I print for example, just the "titulo" or "resumo"?

Or, instead of sending all the information from a table row to a single variable, do I have to send separately into different variables?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you add database data to your session instead of passing it from the controller to the view? Because performance-wise, this is not the best thing to do.

Comment: Show us your controller method.

Comment: And the controller method behind the route where you redirect to does simply display a view? That's overcomplicating things.

Comment: I have a page that shows a brief information about a topic, and when I click on it my controller will receive an ID and then return a view to a new page with the full information about that same topic

Comment: This full information count as : Title, Date , Content, Image , Tags || The brief information count as: Title, Date, Resume, Image, Tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way you can send flash data from the backend:

```
public function show (){

//some code here

return redirect('/')->with('flash', 'message here');
}
```

and in the view you can display it like this:

```
{{session('flash')}}
```

The above will display "message here".

If you have return redirect('/')->with('alert', 'something happened');

```
{{session('alert')}}
```

The above will display "something happened".